# results arima model shifted -Python

Tags: python, arima

I have a time series dataset. I am using python, pandas and statsmodels to try to forecast the next month of my data.

I have daily data:

[image]

First I run autoarima to see what variables I have to put in my Sarimax model:

```py
auto_arima(df['data'],seasonal=True,m=7).summary()
```

[image]

I train my model with this paremeters:

```py
train = df.loc[:'2019-12-31']
test = df.loc['2020-01-01':'2020-01-31']

model = SARIMAX(train['n_transactions'],order=autoarima.order,seasonal_order= autoarima.seasonal_order)
results = model.fit()
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)-1
predictions = results.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False, typ='levels').rename(f'Daily SARIMA{autoarima.order}{autoarima.seasonal_order} Predictions')


ax = test['n_transactions'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,6))
predictions.plot(legend=True)
ax.autoscale(axis='x',tight=True)
ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel);
```

[image]

```py
SARIMA MSE Error: 4.088022969
SARIMA RMSE Error: 2.021885993
SARIMA average:         8.7
SARIMA std: 4.539544925
```

```py
results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The model is not predicting very well, so  I want to see how my model predict the next day. Per each day I am going to train the model again, because for me it's more important only the next month.

```py
all_df = pd.DataFrame()
test = df.iloc[-62:]
i = -62
for index, row in test.iterrows():

    train = df.iloc[:i:]
    model = SARIMAX(train['n_transactions'],order=autoarima.order,seasonal_order= autoarima.seasonal_order)
    results = model.fit()
    start = len(train)
    end = len(train)
    predictions = results.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False, typ='levels')
    test_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'predictions'})
    test_df['predictions'] = predictions
    all_df = pd.concat([all_df, test_df], axis=0, sort=False)
    i += 1

ylabel='n_transactions'
xlabel=''

ax = test['n_transactions'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,6))
all_df['predictions'].plot(legend=True)
ax.autoscale(axis='x',tight=True)
ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel);
```

[image]

It can bee seen from the image bellow that the model is getting a good prediction shifted one day. There is any way to correct this?